# EF6 Many to many Insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My problem is to save existing objects that are part of a many-to-many relationship in a code-first database with EF6.

I am receiving objects from a web service and they look (simplified) like:

```
public class Car
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string CarId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}

public class Contract
{   
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string ContractId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; } 
}
```

I have a code-first database and set the relationship with:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>().HasKey(t => new {t.ContractId});
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasKey(t => new {t.CarId})
            .HasMany(c => c.Contracts)
            .WithMany(c => c.Cars)
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.ToTable("CarContracts");
                x.MapLeftKey("CarId");
                x.MapRightKey("ContractId");
            });
```

When I get a list of cars I can save the first car and EF creates the relation table and the contracts successfully. On the second car the save fails saying "*constraint failed UNIQUE constraint failed: Contracts.ContractId*", since I'm trying to insert a `Contract` with the same `Id` as an already existing Contract.

The solutions I found to this problem is to set the `Contract` in the `dbContext` to Attached:

```
foreach (var contract in car.Contracts)
{
    context.Contract.Attach(contract);
}
```

This throws the same exception as the previous save. When I try to modify the Contract-list of the second car I get a `NotSupportedException`, the only solution I can think of is recreating the car objects and attach the same Contract-object to them, which seems unnecessarily complicated.

Is there any way to tell EF that my two different Contract-objects actually are the same?

Comment: How do you receive/build your car/contracts list?

Comment: Through a WCF service, so Im not creating them myself

Comment: Can you explain why the second insert must be with an existing Car and Contract combination? The error message explicity says that its the UNIQUE-constraint in the Contracts table thats violated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to tell EF that my two different Contract-objects
>   actually are the same?

The only way is they actually are the same object. If they are different instances even having all the same data EF won't recognize them as same entity.

So the only solution is to replace all same id contract instances by a single one.

Or simpler: create an explicit entity representing the N:N relation and then simply build a list to insert as follows:

```
var toInsert = new List<CarContract>();
foreach(var car in cars)
{
    toInsert.AddRange(car.Select(x=>new CarContract {CarId=car.Id,ContractId=x.Id}));
}
```